# Change the visible sate of a link button inside a datalist

Tags: datalist, asplinkbutton

I want to change the visible state and enable state of a link button inside a data list when another button in the same data list is clicked.How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Save")
{
    DataListItem item = (DataListItem)(((LinkButton)(e.CommandSource)).NamingContainer);
    LinkButton lnk=(LinkButton)item.FindControl("LinkButton2");
    lnk.Visible=false;
}
```

This code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am a bit late in answering this but  for `Linkbutton` to change its visible state by using `display:none`

```
 lnk.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```